# What is the mechanism that makes `+` work when defined by + in empty environment?

Tags: r

Here I create an unevaluated expression:

```
e2 <- expression(x+10)
```

If I supply an environment in which `x` is defined like

```
env <- as.environment(list(x=20))
eval(e2,env)
```

R will report an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "+"
```

It is understandable since `env` is an environment created from scratch, that is, it has no parent environment where `+` is defined.

However, if I supply `+` in the list to be converted to an environment like this

```
env <- as.environment(list(x=20,`+`=function(a,b) {a+b}))
eval(e2,env)
```

The evaluation works correctly and yields 30.

However, when I define `+` in the list, it is a binary function whose body also uses + which is defined in `{base}`. I know that function returns are lazily evaluated in R, but why this could work? If `a+b` in the function body is lazily evaluated, when I call `eval` for `e2` within `env`, even though `+` is defined in this environment which has no parent environment, it should still calls `+` in itself, which should end up in endless loop. Why is does not happen like this? What is the mechanism here?

Comment: You might find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html helpful.

Comment: Great to see you here, @hadley! I've read your amazing new book online a month ago. Maybe I miss some point and there are certainly more for me to digest. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The key distinction is the "environment where the function is created" vs "the environment where the function resides"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the environment here:

```
env <- as.environment(list(x=20,`+`=function(a,b) {a+b}))
```

then the function definition is actually defined in the `.GlobalEnv` (namely, where the definition is executed. You can verify this:

```
$ environment(env$`+`)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

This observation is worth being pondered a little: a function can be a member of environment `x`, yet belong to `y` (where “belong to” means that its object lookup uses `y` rather than `x`).

And `.GlobalEnv` knows about `+`, since it is defined somewhere in its parents (accessible via `search()`).

Incidentally, if you had used `list2env` instead of `as.environment`, your initial code would have worked:

```
$ env = list2env(list(x = 20))
$ eval(e2, env)
30
```

The reason is that, unlike `as.environment`, `list2env` by default uses the current environment as the new environment’s parent (this can be controlled via the `parent` argument). `as.environment` by contrast uses the empty environment (when creating an environment from a list).

Comment: amazing quick reply! thanks! It is still mind blowing that a function can be a member of one environment but performs object lookup in another environment. Is there a reason that makes it straightforward?

Comment: @KunRen The reason is that a function’s environment is the place where its definition was executed – in your case, that’s the global environment. If you wanted to create a function inside `env` you could use `within` or `local`. I don’t know the reason for this behaviour but it does make sense, and it’s required for the implementation of packages, see http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/.

Comment: Very helpful article!

Comment: But there's another question: Now that `+` has `.GlobalEnv` as its parent environment, how can I define a function that has a local parent environment. Like: `env <- as.environment(list(x=1))`, then I call `env$f1 <- function() {print(x); print(environment())}`, and then `env$f1()`, an error occurs: `Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found`. It is because when `env$f1` is executed, its local function environment belongs to `.GlobalEnv` which does not contain `x`. Is there a decent way to define `f1` so that its perform symbol lookup in `env` first?

Comment: @KunRen Like my previous comment said, you can use `local` or `within` to define a function inside the environment. However, be sure to actually give your `env` a suitable parent environment – in other words, don’t use `as.environment`, use `list2env` as my answer shows. That way, functions can be defined locally (with `local` or `within`) and can *still* find symbols in the global environment.